Is squared geodesic distance about a point convex when defined on a convex ball centered at that point?
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Let $x \in \mathcal{M}$, and let $r_x >0$ be the convexity radius at $x$. Let $B \subset \mathcal{M}$ be a geodesic ball centered at $x$ with radius is less than $r_x$. Define the function $f(y):=d(x,y)^2$, where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the geodesic distance. My question is, is $f:B \to \mathbb{R}$ a geodesically convex function? If not, is $f$ geodesically convex for sufficiently small radius on the geodesic ball $B$? How would one go about proving this?
I am using the following definitions for geodesic convexity:
A set $A \subset \mathcal{M}$ is geodesically convex if for any $x,y \in A$, there exists a unique minimizing geodesic contained in $A$. A function $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is geodesically convex if for any $x,y \in A$, we have $f(c(t)) \leq (1-t)f(x) + t f(y)$ for $t \in [0,1]$, where $c(t)$ is the unique minimizing geodesic from $x$ to $y$ contained in $A$.

It is true for sufficiently small metric balls. This simply fallows from strict convexity of the square distance function in the Euclidean case.

The proof of convexity of $d^2$ is pretty much a part of the proof of existence of a convex neighborhood. See for instance page 75 of do Carmo's book.
